# Building a pre-loader for performance gains in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

As the title states, I am building a pre-loader for Wordpress running on PHP 7.3.5+ that will deliver performance boosts in loading, as well as metrics such as Google Page Speed.

This is something that we do at work, and I could quite easily copy what has been used there but feel it is 'stolen knowledge'. I could be writing anything and have very little understanding of what I am typing as it was developed by seniors.

So, given that I know what the basics of the pre-loader are (load critical styles, defer certain scripts, remove unwanted WP scripts) I had a bash at creating one myself that appears to work:

```php
// If there are problems with caching, 
// change this version number
define('CACHE_VERSION', '1.0.0');

class WpboilerInliner {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'init') );
        add_action( 'wp_head', array(&$this, 'addCriticalCss') );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array(&$this, 'addGeneralCss') );
    }

    // This will add the critical CSS to the header
    function addCriticalCss() {
        // Set to not load in the admin as this will 'break' it
        if(!is_admin()) {
            $criticalFonts = '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
                              <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
                              <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> ';
    
            $criticalCSSContent = file_get_contents( get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/atf.css' );
            $criticalCSS = "<style type='text/css'>
                                <!-- BEGIN CRITICAL STYLES -->
                                {$criticalCSSContent}
                                <!-- END CRITICAL STYLES -->
                            </style>";

            echo $criticalFonts . $criticalCSS;

        }
    }

    // General styles, these will be added in the footer
    function addGeneralCss() {

        // Add the filename to be added to the footer(below the fold) here
        // Add files in their correct cascade order
        // e.g filename.css
        // filename.min.css 
        // subdirectory/filename.css
        $generalCssFileName = array(
            'general.css',
            'type.css',
        );

        foreach($generalCssFileName as $cssFileName) {
            $linkFormat = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/%s?ver=%s" />';
        
            $cssLink = sprintf($linkFormat, $cssFileName, CACHE_VERSION);

            echo $cssLink;
        }
    }

    function init() {

        // Remove everything to do with emojis
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
        remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
        remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
        remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );

        remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
        remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );

        add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojis_tinymce' );
        add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch', 10, 2 );

        // Remove version number from header
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );

        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );

        // Removes shortlink
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head' );

        // Removes feed links 
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );

        // // Removes comments feed 
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );

        /**
         * Filter function used to remove the TinyMCE emoji plugin 
         * 
         * @param array $plugins 
         * @return array Difference between the two arrays
        */
        function disable_emojis_tinymce( $plugins ) {

            if( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
                return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
            } else {
                return array();
            }

        } 
        
        /**
         * Remove emoji CDN hostname from DNS prefetching hints
         * 
         * @param array $urls URLs to print for resource hints 
         * @param string $relation_type The relation type the URLs are printed for 
         * @return array Difference between the two arrays 
        */
        function disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch( $urls, $relation_type ) {

            if( 'dns-prefetch' == $relation_type ) {
                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/formatting.php */
                $emoji_svg_url = apply_filters( 'emoji_svg_url', 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2/svg/' );

                $urls = array_diff( $urls, array( $emoji_svg_url ) );
            }

            return $urls;

        }

        // Load JS files
        wp_enqueue_script('wpboiler-critical-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/atf.min.js', array(), CACHE_VERSION, false);
        wp_enqueue_script('wpboiler-general-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/general.min.js', array(), CACHE_VERSION, true);
 
    }

}

$wpboilerInliner = new WpboilerInliner();
```

Are there ways of improving this? It has not yet been tested with plugins, but on a basic install it seems to work as expected (from what I can tell). I came into an issue with the admin area when trying to load in the fonts and the critical styles which is why they are wrapped in `!is_admin()`. Functions `disable_emojis_tinymce()` and `disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch()` were taken from a post by [Kinsta](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-emojis-wordpress/).

Are there methods I can improve here? Are there some major errors that I am likely to encounter with what I have currently written? My PHP knowledge is limited so I understand some of the more basic concepts such as `sprintf` and the basic use of arrays and loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly haven’t used Wordpress much - just assisted with a company project that used it about 6 years ago. The biggest thing I notice is that the syntax used to declare arrays is the legacy syntax, which is fine but could be converted to [the shorter syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax) - i.e. `[]`. I know it only saves five characters but it is more in-line with  JavaScript's shorthand array declaration style.

For instance, these three lines in the constructor:

> ```
> add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'init') );
> add_action( 'wp_head', array(&$this, 'addCriticalCss') );
> add_action( 'wp_footer', array(&$this, 'addGeneralCss') );
> ```

Could be updated to:

```
add_action( 'init', [&$this, 'init'] );
add_action( 'wp_head', [&$this, 'addCriticalCss'] );
add_action( 'wp_footer', [$this, 'addGeneralCss'] );
```

And I could be wrong but the `&` before `$this` can be removed. The documentation for [passing callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing) states:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1. Accessing protected and private methods from within a class is allowed.

Notice that it doesn't state the object needs to be passed by reference.

---

In the function `addGeneralCss()` there is a loop over file names.

> ```
> $generalCssFileName = array(
>     'general.css',
>     'type.css',
> );
>
> foreach($generalCssFileName as $cssFileName) {
>     $linkFormat = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/%s?ver=%s" />';
>
>     $cssLink = sprintf($linkFormat, $cssFileName, CACHE_VERSION);
>
>     echo $cssLink;
> }
> ```

That is 9+ lines to add two `<link>` tags. While it is great to avoid repetition, making a loop for two items may not be worth the cost of setting up the loop.

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/general.css?ver=' . CACHE_VERSION . '" />';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/type.css?ver=' . CACHE_VERSION . '" />';
```

---

The method `init` is a bit long. There are multiple calls to `remove_action()` with `wp_head` as the first parameter, although some calls have a third parameter. If it wasn't for that third parameter in some cases it may be simple to loop over an array containing values for the second parameter.

---

The function `disable_emojis_tinymce()` contains an `if` with an `else` block.

> ```
> if( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
>     return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
> } else {
>    return array();
> }
> ```

The `if` block contains a `return` statement so the `else` can be removed.

```
if( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
    return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
}
return array();
```

If the line in the `if` block was longer, then it may be worth reversing the logic, to decrease the indentation level:

```
if( !is_array( $plugins ) ) {
    return array();
}
return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
```

This concept of avoiding the `else` is part of the Object Calisthenics - [you can read more about it here](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#2-dont-use-the-else-keyword).

Comment: Thanks for that, I've only just had an opportunity to look through the answers you gave and they were all very useful. With the `add_action()`s, I'll have a read through what is possible and what can be omitted to try and clean that up a bit. But all very clear in your responses.